# How to change of size of a table that is inside another table?

Tags: html, css

I need to change the size of warranty table that is nested inside one of the td's of the other table, but I cannot change its size by changing height or width. What do I do?

Here is the code but if you want a simplified explaination I have a table that is inside the  of another table and I am trying to resize it.

```html
<div class="single_ticket_container">
  <div style="background: linear-gradient(to left, rgb(187, 230, 241), rgb(228, 245, 249));">
    <div class="label_header_container"><span id="ticket_label_ticket_num">Ticket #: </span><span class="ticket_header_data" id="ticket_header_ticket_num">01097P6YRXW</span></div>
    <div class="label_header_container"><span class="ticket_header_label">Final Date: </span><span class="ticket_header_data">10/03/2017</span></div>
    <div class="label_header_container"><span class="ticket_header_label">Order Type: </span><span class="ticket_header_data">SAL</span></div>
    <div class="label_header_container"><span class="ticket_header_label">Status Code: </span><span class="ticket_header_data">F</span></div>
    <div class="label_header_container"><span class="ticket_header_label">HFC: </span> <span class="ticket_header_data">P35</span></div>
  </div>
  <div class="overlay_table"></div>
  <div>
    <div class="quicktable-actions table donatello"></div>
    <table id="QuickTable" class="table donatello" style="margin: 0px;">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="donatello color-primary" data-align="auto">
            <div style="display: flex;">
              <div>SKU</div>
            </div>
          </th>
          <th class="donatello color-primary" data-align="auto">
            <div style="display: flex;">
              <div>VE CD</div>
            </div>
          </th>
          <th class="donatello color-primary" data-align="auto">
            <div style="display: flex;">
              <div>Vendor Stock Number</div>
            </div>
          </th>
          <th class="donatello color-primary" data-align="auto">
            <div style="display: flex;">
              <div>Description</div>
            </div>
          </th>
          <th class="donatello color-primary" data-align="auto">
            <div style="display: flex;">
              <div>Av. Cr.</div>
            </div>
          </th>
          <th class="donatello color-primary" data-align="auto">
            <div style="display: flex;">
              <div>Qty</div>
            </div>
          </th>
          <th class="donatello color-primary" data-align="auto">
            <div style="display: flex;">
              <div>Ser Qty</div>
            </div>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr data-even="true">
          <td style="background: white;">
            <div><span class="SKU_link">399054801</span><span style="display: block;">SO Line Comment:</span><textarea type="text" maxlength="70" placeholder="70 characters"></textarea></div>
          </td>
          <td style="background: white;">GOAK</td>
          <td style="background: white;">HGXLGTD</td>
          <td style="background: white;">
            <div>
              <div>
                <div>
                  <span class="header">Warranty Information:</span>
                  <table class="warranty_table">
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Upholstery:</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Frame</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Spring</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Mechs</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Cores</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Mattresses</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Fabric</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Leather</th>
                    <tr>
                      <td></td>
                      <td>2yr</td>
                      <td>2yr</td>
                      <td>life</td>
                      <td>5yr</td>
                      <td>N/A</td>
                      <td>1yr</td>
                      <td>5yr</td>
                    </tr>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Case Goods</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Frame</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Spring</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Mechs</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Cores</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Mattresses</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Fabric</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Leather</th>
                    <tr>
                      <td></td>
                      <td>2yr</td>
                      <td>2yr</td>
                      <td>life</td>
                      <td>5yr</td>
                      <td>N/A</td>
                      <td>1yr</td>
                      <td>5yr</td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td style="background: white;">
            <div></div>
          </td>
          <td style="background: white;">1</td>
          <td style="background: white;">
            <div><span data-isdis="true"><input disabled="" data-finaldate="10/03/2017" data-purchaseqty="1" data-sku="399054801" data-del="01097P6YRXW" class="ser_qty_input" type="number"></span></div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-odd="true">
          <td style="background: white;">
            <div><span class="SKU_link">364054800</span><span style="display: block;">SO Line Comment:</span><textarea type="text" maxlength="70" placeholder="70 characters"></textarea></div>
          </td>
          <td style="background: white;">GOAK</td>
          <td style="background: white;">XLGTD54H-8P BROOKS (F.D.)</td>
          <td style="background: white;">
            <div>
              <div>
                <div>
                  <span class="header">Warranty Information:</span>
                  <table class="warranty_table">
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Upholstery:</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Frame</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Spring</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Mechs</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Cores</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Mattresses</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Fabric</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Leather</th>
                    <tr>
                      <td></td>
                      <td>2yr</td>
                      <td>2yr</td>
                      <td>life</td>
                      <td>5yr</td>
                      <td>N/A</td>
                      <td>1yr</td>
                      <td>5yr</td>
                    </tr>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Case Goods</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Frame</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Spring</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Mechs</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Cores</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Mattresses</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Fabric</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Leather</th>
                    <tr>
                      <td></td>
                      <td>2yr</td>
                      <td>2yr</td>
                      <td>life</td>
                      <td>5yr</td>
                      <td>N/A</td>
                      <td>1yr</td>
                      <td>5yr</td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td style="background: white;">
            <div></div>
          </td>
          <td style="background: white;">1</td>
          <td style="background: white;">
            <div><span data-isdis="false"><input data-finaldate="10/03/2017" data-purchaseqty="1" data-sku="364054800" data-del="01097P6YRXW" class="ser_qty_input" type="number"></span></div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-even="true">
          <td style="background: white;">
            <div><span class="SKU_link">365054801</span><span style="display: block;">SO Line Comment:</span><textarea type="text" maxlength="70" placeholder="70 characters"></textarea></div>
          </td>
          <td style="background: white;">GOAK</td>
          <td style="background: white;">ATD60H-8P (F.D.)</td>
          <td style="background: white;">
            <div>
              <div>
                <div>
                  <span class="header">Warranty Information:</span>
                  <table class="warranty_table">
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Upholstery:</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Frame</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Spring</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Mechs</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Cores</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Mattresses</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Fabric</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Leather</th>
                    <tr>
                      <td></td>
                      <td>2yr</td>
                      <td>2yr</td>
                      <td>life</td>
                      <td>5yr</td>
                      <td>N/A</td>
                      <td>1yr</td>
                      <td>5yr</td>
                    </tr>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Case Goods</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Frame</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Spring</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Mechs</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Cores</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Mattresses</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Fabric</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Leather</th>
                    <tr>
                      <td></td>
                      <td>2yr</td>
                      <td>2yr</td>
                      <td>life</td>
                      <td>5yr</td>
                      <td>N/A</td>
                      <td>1yr</td>
                      <td>5yr</td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td style="background: white;">
            <div></div>
          </td>
          <td style="background: white;">1</td>
          <td style="background: white;">
            <div><span data-isdis="false"><input data-finaldate="10/03/2017" data-purchaseqty="1" data-sku="365054801" data-del="01097P6YRXW" class="ser_qty_input" type="number"></span></div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-odd="true">
          <td style="background: white;">
            <div><span class="SKU_link">365054801</span><span style="display: block;">SO Line Comment:</span><textarea type="text" maxlength="70" placeholder="70 characters"></textarea></div>
          </td>
          <td style="background: white;">GOAK</td>
          <td style="background: white;">ATD60H-8P (F.D.)</td>
          <td style="background: white;">
            <div>
              <div>
                <div>
                  <span class="header">Warranty Information:</span>
                  <table class="warranty_table">
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Upholstery:</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Frame</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Spring</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Mechs</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Cores</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Mattresses</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Fabric</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Leather</th>
                    <tr>
                      <td></td>
                      <td>2yr</td>
                      <td>2yr</td>
                      <td>life</td>
                      <td>5yr</td>
                      <td>N/A</td>
                      <td>1yr</td>
                      <td>5yr</td>
                    </tr>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Case Goods</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Frame</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Spring</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Mechs</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Cores</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Mattresses</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Fabric</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Leather</th>
                    <tr>
                      <td></td>
                      <td>2yr</td>
                      <td>2yr</td>
                      <td>life</td>
                      <td>5yr</td>
                      <td>N/A</td>
                      <td>1yr</td>
                      <td>5yr</td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td style="background: white;">
            <div></div>
          </td>
          <td style="background: white;">1</td>
          <td style="background: white;">
            <div><span data-isdis="false"><input data-finaldate="10/03/2017" data-purchaseqty="1" data-sku="365054801" data-del="01097P6YRXW" class="ser_qty_input" type="number"></span></div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-even="true">
          <td style="background: white;">
            <div><span class="SKU_link">202239352</span><span style="display: block;">SO Line Comment:</span><textarea type="text" maxlength="70" placeholder="70 characters"></textarea></div>
          </td>
          <td style="background: white;">RF14</td>
          <td style="background: white;">393-52PWR STYLUS</td>
          <td style="background: white;">
            <div>
              <div>
                <div>
                  <span class="header">Warranty Information:</span>
                  <table class="warranty_table">
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Upholstery:</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Frame</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Spring</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Mechs</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Cores</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Mattresses</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Fabric</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Leather</th>
                    <tr>
                      <td></td>
                      <td>2yr</td>
                      <td>2yr</td>
                      <td>life</td>
                      <td>5yr</td>
                      <td>N/A</td>
                      <td>1yr</td>
                      <td>5yr</td>
                    </tr>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Case Goods</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Frame</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Spring</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Mechs</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Cores</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Mattresses</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Fabric</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Leather</th>
                    <tr>
                      <td></td>
                      <td>2yr</td>
                      <td>2yr</td>
                      <td>life</td>
                      <td>5yr</td>
                      <td>N/A</td>
                      <td>1yr</td>
                      <td>5yr</td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td style="background: white;">
            <div></div>
          </td>
          <td style="background: white;">2</td>
          <td style="background: white;">
            <div><span data-isdis="false"><input data-finaldate="10/03/2017" data-purchaseqty="2" data-sku="202239352" data-del="01097P6YRXW" class="ser_qty_input" type="number"></span></div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

add style ='width:1000px' inside  or add witdth:1000px to your css class named warranty_table.

The result should look like this

```html
<div class="single_ticket_container">
  <div style="background: linear-gradient(to left, rgb(187, 230, 241), rgb(228, 245, 249));">
    <div class="label_header_container"><span id="ticket_label_ticket_num">Ticket #: </span><span class="ticket_header_data" id="ticket_header_ticket_num">01097P6YRXW</span></div>
    <div class="label_header_container"><span class="ticket_header_label">Final Date: </span><span class="ticket_header_data">10/03/2017</span></div>
    <div class="label_header_container"><span class="ticket_header_label">Order Type: </span><span class="ticket_header_data">SAL</span></div>
    <div class="label_header_container"><span class="ticket_header_label">Status Code: </span><span class="ticket_header_data">F</span></div>
    <div class="label_header_container"><span class="ticket_header_label">HFC: </span> <span class="ticket_header_data">P35</span></div>
  </div>
  <div class="overlay_table"></div>
  <div>
    <div class="quicktable-actions table donatello"></div>
    <table id="QuickTable" class="table donatello" style="margin: 0px;">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="donatello color-primary" data-align="auto">
            <div style="display: flex;">
              <div>SKU</div>
            </div>
          </th>
          <th class="donatello color-primary" data-align="auto">
            <div style="display: flex;">
              <div>VE CD</div>
            </div>
          </th>
          <th class="donatello color-primary" data-align="auto">
            <div style="display: flex;">
              <div>Vendor Stock Number</div>
            </div>
          </th>
          <th class="donatello color-primary" data-align="auto">
            <div style="display: flex;">
              <div>Description</div>
            </div>
          </th>
          <th class="donatello color-primary" data-align="auto">
            <div style="display: flex;">
              <div>Av. Cr.</div>
            </div>
          </th>
          <th class="donatello color-primary" data-align="auto">
            <div style="display: flex;">
              <div>Qty</div>
            </div>
          </th>
          <th class="donatello color-primary" data-align="auto">
            <div style="display: flex;">
              <div>Ser Qty</div>
            </div>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr data-even="true">
          <td style="background: white;">
            <div><span class="SKU_link">399054801</span><span style="display: block;">SO Line Comment:</span><textarea type="text" maxlength="70" placeholder="70 characters"></textarea></div>
          </td>
          <td style="background: white;">GOAK</td>
          <td style="background: white;">HGXLGTD</td>
          <td style="background: white;">
            <div>
              <div>
                <div>
                  <span class="header">Warranty Information:</span>
                  <table class="warranty_table" style='width:1000px;'>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Upholstery:</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Frame</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Spring</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Mechs</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Cores</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Mattresses</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Fabric</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Leather</th>
                    <tr>
                      <td></td>
                      <td>2yr</td>
                      <td>2yr</td>
                      <td>life</td>
                      <td>5yr</td>
                      <td>N/A</td>
                      <td>1yr</td>
                      <td>5yr</td>
                    </tr>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Case Goods</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Frame</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Spring</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Mechs</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Cores</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Mattresses</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Fabric</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Leather</th>
                    <tr>
                      <td></td>
                      <td>2yr</td>
                      <td>2yr</td>
                      <td>life</td>
                      <td>5yr</td>
                      <td>N/A</td>
                      <td>1yr</td>
                      <td>5yr</td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td style="background: white;">
            <div></div>
          </td>
          <td style="background: white;">1</td>
          <td style="background: white;">
            <div><span data-isdis="true"><input disabled="" data-finaldate="10/03/2017" data-purchaseqty="1" data-sku="399054801" data-del="01097P6YRXW" class="ser_qty_input" type="number"></span></div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-odd="true">
          <td style="background: white;">
            <div><span class="SKU_link">364054800</span><span style="display: block;">SO Line Comment:</span><textarea type="text" maxlength="70" placeholder="70 characters"></textarea></div>
          </td>
          <td style="background: white;">GOAK</td>
          <td style="background: white;">XLGTD54H-8P BROOKS (F.D.)</td>
          <td style="background: white;">
            <div>
              <div>
                <div>
                  <span class="header">Warranty Information:</span>
                  <table class="warranty_table" style='width:1000px;>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Upholstery:</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Frame</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Spring</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Mechs</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Cores</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Mattresses</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Fabric</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Leather</th>
                    <tr>
                      <td></td>
                      <td>2yr</td>
                      <td>2yr</td>
                      <td>life</td>
                      <td>5yr</td>
                      <td>N/A</td>
                      <td>1yr</td>
                      <td>5yr</td>
                    </tr>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Case Goods</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Frame</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Spring</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Mechs</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Cores</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Mattresses</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Fabric</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Leather</th>
                    <tr>
                      <td></td>
                      <td>2yr</td>
                      <td>2yr</td>
                      <td>life</td>
                      <td>5yr</td>
                      <td>N/A</td>
                      <td>1yr</td>
                      <td>5yr</td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td style="background: white;">
            <div></div>
          </td>
          <td style="background: white;">1</td>
          <td style="background: white;">
            <div><span data-isdis="false"><input data-finaldate="10/03/2017" data-purchaseqty="1" data-sku="364054800" data-del="01097P6YRXW" class="ser_qty_input" type="number"></span></div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-even="true">
          <td style="background: white;">
            <div><span class="SKU_link">365054801</span><span style="display: block;">SO Line Comment:</span><textarea type="text" maxlength="70" placeholder="70 characters"></textarea></div>
          </td>
          <td style="background: white;">GOAK</td>
          <td style="background: white;">ATD60H-8P (F.D.)</td>
          <td style="background: white;">
            <div>
              <div>
                <div>
                  <span class="header">Warranty Information:</span>
                  <table class="warranty_table" style='width:1000px;>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Upholstery:</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Frame</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Spring</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Mechs</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Cores</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Mattresses</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Fabric</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Leather</th>
                    <tr>
                      <td></td>
                      <td>2yr</td>
                      <td>2yr</td>
                      <td>life</td>
                      <td>5yr</td>
                      <td>N/A</td>
                      <td>1yr</td>
                      <td>5yr</td>
                    </tr>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Case Goods</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Frame</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Spring</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Mechs</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Cores</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Mattresses</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Fabric</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Leather</th>
                    <tr>
                      <td></td>
                      <td>2yr</td>
                      <td>2yr</td>
                      <td>life</td>
                      <td>5yr</td>
                      <td>N/A</td>
                      <td>1yr</td>
                      <td>5yr</td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td style="background: white;">
            <div></div>
          </td>
          <td style="background: white;">1</td>
          <td style="background: white;">
            <div><span data-isdis="false"><input data-finaldate="10/03/2017" data-purchaseqty="1" data-sku="365054801" data-del="01097P6YRXW" class="ser_qty_input" type="number"></span></div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-odd="true">
          <td style="background: white;">
            <div><span class="SKU_link">365054801</span><span style="display: block;">SO Line Comment:</span><textarea type="text" maxlength="70" placeholder="70 characters"></textarea></div>
          </td>
          <td style="background: white;">GOAK</td>
          <td style="background: white;">ATD60H-8P (F.D.)</td>
          <td style="background: white;">
            <div>
              <div>
                <div>
                  <span class="header">Warranty Information:</span>
                  <table class="warranty_table" style='width:1000px;>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Upholstery:</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Frame</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Spring</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Mechs</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Cores</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Mattresses</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Fabric</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Leather</th>
                    <tr>
                      <td></td>
                      <td>2yr</td>
                      <td>2yr</td>
                      <td>life</td>
                      <td>5yr</td>
                      <td>N/A</td>
                      <td>1yr</td>
                      <td>5yr</td>
                    </tr>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Case Goods</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Frame</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Spring</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Mechs</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Cores</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Mattresses</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Fabric</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Leather</th>
                    <tr>
                      <td></td>
                      <td>2yr</td>
                      <td>2yr</td>
                      <td>life</td>
                      <td>5yr</td>
                      <td>N/A</td>
                      <td>1yr</td>
                      <td>5yr</td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td style="background: white;">
            <div></div>
          </td>
          <td style="background: white;">1</td>
          <td style="background: white;">
            <div><span data-isdis="false"><input data-finaldate="10/03/2017" data-purchaseqty="1" data-sku="365054801" data-del="01097P6YRXW" class="ser_qty_input" type="number"></span></div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-even="true">
          <td style="background: white;">
            <div><span class="SKU_link">202239352</span><span style="display: block;">SO Line Comment:</span><textarea type="text" maxlength="70" placeholder="70 characters"></textarea></div>
          </td>
          <td style="background: white;">RF14</td>
          <td style="background: white;">393-52PWR STYLUS</td>
          <td style="background: white;">
            <div>
              <div>
                <div>
                  <span class="header">Warranty Information:</span>
                  <table class="warranty_table" style='width:1000px;>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Upholstery:</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Frame</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Spring</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Mechs</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Cores</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Mattresses</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Fabric</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Leather</th>
                    <tr>
                      <td></td>
                      <td>2yr</td>
                      <td>2yr</td>
                      <td>life</td>
                      <td>5yr</td>
                      <td>N/A</td>
                      <td>1yr</td>
                      <td>5yr</td>
                    </tr>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Case Goods</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Frame</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Spring</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Mechs</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Cores</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Mattresses</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Fabric</th>
                    <th class="table_heading_warranty">Leather</th>
                    <tr>
                      <td></td>
                      <td>2yr</td>
                      <td>2yr</td>
                      <td>life</td>
                      <td>5yr</td>
                      <td>N/A</td>
                      <td>1yr</td>
                      <td>5yr</td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td style="background: white;">
            <div></div>
          </td>
          <td style="background: white;">2</td>
          <td style="background: white;">
            <div><span data-isdis="false"><input data-finaldate="10/03/2017" data-purchaseqty="2" data-sku="202239352" data-del="01097P6YRXW" class="ser_qty_input" type="number"></span></div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```